# Factoring polynomials - slightly odd case

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have tried to understand the last step in this question, but I don't quite see the logic

Factor 
$$ x^2+4x+4-9y^2$$

The first thing I thought was that I could factor by grouping, however this is not successful. So, the next thing I tried to do was factor the

$$ x^2+4x+4$$ part to get $$ (x+2)^2-9y^2$$

Then factor out the common terms in the y-portion:

$$ (x+2)^2-(3y)^2$$
But this is as far as I get. I eventually looked up the answer:

$$(x+2-3y)(x+2+3y)$$Is this some difference distributive rule?

Comment: $A^2 - B^2 = (A-B)(A+B)$

Comment: Or $\rm\ X^2 = B^2\iff X = \pm B\ $ and these roots yield the factorization $$\rm X^2 - B^2\ =\ (X-B)\:(X+B) $$ which works even if you have no knowledge of difference of squares factorization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably familiar with the "difference of squares" rule: 
$$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b).$$
Note that your situation with $(x+2)^2-(3y)^2$ is just a difference of squares, where we have  $a=x+2$ and $b=3y$. Thus, we get the factorization
$$(x+2-3y)(x+2+3y).$$

The difference of squares rule can be proven by repeated use of the [distributive property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property):
$$\begin{align*}(a-b)(a+b)&=((a-b)\times a)+((a-b)\times b)\\&=(a^2-ba)+(ab-b^2)\\&=a^2-ab+ab-b^2\\&=a^2-b^2\end{align*}$$